# Refer to the calculated column within the column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, lag

Column ORtg_home contains values differ from zeros and zeros. My purpose is to create a new column (X) in which there are only values without zeros. (After the first home game. If it would be a zero then give back the last value which is not zero from ORtg_home).

| Team | Game_total | Home_away | Game_home | Game_away | ORtg_avg | ORtg_home | x |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ATL | 1 | away | 0 | 1 | 100 | 0 | 0 |
| ATL | 2 | home | 1 | 1 | 101 | 102 | 102 |
| ATL | 3 | away | 1 | 2 | 104 | 0 | 102 |
| ATL | 4 | away | 1 | 3 | 106 | 0 | 102 |

I tried the code below:

```
  SELECT 
      [ORtg_home]
      ,(CASE WHEN [Home_away] = 'home' THEN ([ORtg_home])
    ELSE 
        LAG(ORtg_home, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY Team ORDER BY [Game_total] ASC, Home_away ASC) END) as XXX
  FROM [table1]
```

This gives 102 for the 3rd game, however the 4th game value in column x is still 0. Teams may vary. Currently table does not contain the date of the game, but it can be added.

```
CREATE TABLE [test1]
(
      [Team]            VARCHAR(3)
      ,[Game_total]     INT
      ,[Home_away]      VARCHAR(4)
      ,[Game_home]      INT
      ,[Game_away]      INT


      ,[ORtg_avg]       FLOAT
      ,[ORtg_home]      FLOAT
      ,[x]              FLOAT

      )

INSERT INTO [test1]
          [Team], [Game_total], [Home_away], [Game_home], [Game_away, [ORtg_avg] ,[ORtg_home]       
            
VALUES (ATL, 1, 'away', 0, 1, 100, 0)
VALUES (ATL, 2, 'home', 1, 1, 101, 102)
VALUES (ATL, 3, 'away', 1, 2, 104, 0)
VALUES (ATL, 4, 'away', 1, 3, 106, 0)
```

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format. Tag your DBMS.

Comment: You can't have a calculated column reference itself. So that idea is a non starter, give example data and show your desired end results for that data so we can see how best to do it

Comment: Having a calculated column referencing itself doesn't make any sense. It would effectively cause an infinite bloop, as each time it references itself the value would change, meaning it would infinitely need to be recalculated.

Comment: @Larnu referencing it inside LAG wouldn't cause such an infinite loop. It would just use the value that column evaluated to in the previous row. This would be useful sometimes but it isn't permitted anyway

Comment: For me it was so obvious, btw thanks I modified it. I hope it is the proper format.  Referencing itself.. seems somehow logical. Maybe because lag gives back the last row. Unfortunately I cannot use 1 as a constanc since it is vary how many home/away games come in a row.

Comment: FYI: You really don't want to be using a `float` datatype unless you are storing scientific data. It doesn't store numbers as you might expect. `Decimal` is usually a far better choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be easier if `LAST_VALUE` supported the `IGNORE_NULLS` clause as then you could just convert the zeroes to `NULL` and use that.

In the absence of this you can use the approach below ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b5443865dd77d242c78085949aa2267b))

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT  *, 
        MAX(FORMAT(Game_total,'D10') + FORMAT(NULLIF(ORtg_home,0),'R')) OVER (PARTITION BY Team ORDER BY [Game_total] ASC) AS _x
FROM test1
)
SELECT Team,
       Game_total,
       Home_away,
       Game_home,
       Game_away,
       ORtg_avg,
       ORtg_home,
       COALESCE(SUBSTRING(_x, 11, 100), 0E0) AS x
FROM   T
```

Comment: Is ignore nulls supported in SQL server?  How should I add it to the code below?    

LAST_VALUE (ORtg_home) OVER (PARTITION BY Team ORDER BY Game_total ASC) END)

Comment: In the meantime I tried your approach, it is great and working so really thank you.
Now I'm trying to understand how _x calculation works.  May you explain it? How should I modify if ORtg_home is a Float, not INT and what if I wanna add some other value differ from zero? (this would be the case if there is no home game yet)

Comment: @tomatoma37 - (1) No `IGNORE_NULLS` isn't supported - or I would have used that. (2) Updated for `float` datatype. (3) To use something other than zero change the zero in `NULLIF(ORtg_home,0)`

Comment: and for explanation see https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/last-non-null-puzzle